# Setting up pixel array data for Evas Image Object

Tags: c, image, efl

This question is about use of `evas_object_image_data_set` function.
 Say, I have some pixel array in RGBA format. I make a transformation on it to become ARGB, suitable for Evas Image Object.
 Next thing I create a window `with elm_win_add`.
 Then I create image object with `evas_object_image_add(evas_object_evas_get(window))`.
 After that I call to `evas_object_image_fill_set`, then `evas_object_image_size_set`.
 Then I call `evas_object_image_data_set` and finally I call `evas_object_image_data_update_add` with approriate region for my image.
 After all this done I see nothing but black box. Am I doing something wrong?

P.S.: using efl version 1.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setup the image object as described in the question.
2. Get a void pointer to the raw image data with `evas_object_image_data_get`, with `EINA_TRUE` in argument `for_writing`.
3. Modify the data as needed.
4. Call `evas_object_image_data_set` with the void pointer as argument.

Comment: Yes, that works. But the problem was that I packed the evas image object to elm_box object and image became invisible. Dunno why.